# append multiple csv data to a single csv file based on server name

Tags: powershell

Currently i have multiple csv files for each server which is based on service name.

each service details having different file header. i need to merge them to one

below are the data

***sum_devas1.devad.myworldpanel.comcheck_check_cpu.csv***

```
idle_AVERAGE    idle_MAX    idle_MIN    iowait_AVERAGE  iowait_MAX  iowait_MIN  irq_AVERAGE irq_MAX irq_MIN nice_AVERAGE    nice_MAX    nice_MIN    softirq_AVERAGE softirq_MAX softirq_MIN system_AVERAGE  system_MAX  system_MIN  user_AVERAGE    user_MAX    user_MIN    ServerName  Start Time  End Time
16.35289038 16.4473816  16.1616047  0.063374356 0.098422523 0.050224161 0   0   0   1.22E-05    7.27E-05    0   0.000824397 0.002787119 3.11E-05    0.07319389  0.120766931 0.040373169 0.106745959 0.232386044 0.052443433 devas1.devad.myworldpanel.com   1597044600  1599633000
```

***sum_devas1.devad.myworldpanel.comcheck_interface_eth0.csv***

```
rx_AVERAGE  rx_MAX  rx_MIN  tx_AVERAGE  tx_MAX  tx_MIN  ServerName  Start Time  End Time
20538.44384 73426.92533 1886.881034 6355.250931 20152.27358 1817.357994 devas1.devad.myworldpanel.com   1597044600  1599633000
```

***sum_devetl1.devad.myworldpanel.comcheck_check_cpu.csv***

```
idle_AVERAGE    idle_MAX    idle_MIN    iowait_AVERAGE  iowait_MAX  iowait_MIN  irq_AVERAGE irq_MAX irq_MIN nice_AVERAGE    nice_MAX    nice_MIN    softirq_AVERAGE softirq_MAX softirq_MIN system_AVERAGE  system_MAX  system_MIN  user_AVERAGE    user_MAX    user_MIN    ServerName  Start Time  End Time
16.3233089  16.40686623 16.19631629 0.035061225 0.050890455 0.02644959  0   0   0   0   0   0   0.003819214 0.009045636 0.001082091 0.108321254 0.133326619 0.094285539 0.126921523 0.229612047 0.060476719 devetl1.devad.myworldpanel.com  1597044600  1599633000
```

***sum_devetl1.devad.myworldpanel.comcheck_interface_eth0.csv***

```
rx_AVERAGE  rx_MAX  rx_MIN  tx_AVERAGE  tx_MAX  tx_MIN  ServerName  Start Time  End Time
734168.6231 1112739.696 489717.1196 735441.5674 1133400.164 472900.3149 devetl1.devad.myworldpanel.com  1597044600  1599633000
```

the output should be in a single csv(same sheet or multiple sheets based on servicenames) keeping all the headers

```
***(all the records for the first service)
rx_AVERAGE  rx_MAX  rx_MIN  tx_AVERAGE  tx_MAX  tx_MIN  ServerName  Start Time  End Time
20538.44384 73426.92533 1886.881034 6355.250931 20152.27358 1817.357994 devas1.devad.myworldpanel.com   1597044600  1599633000


734168.6231 1112739.696 489717.1196 735441.5674 1133400.164 472900.3149 devetl1.devad.myworldpanel.com  1597044600  1599633000




***(all the records for the second service)***

idle_AVERAGE    idle_MAX    idle_MIN    iowait_AVERAGE  iowait_MAX  iowait_MIN  irq_AVERAGE irq_MAX irq_MIN nice_AVERAGE    nice_MAX    nice_MIN    softirq_AVERAGE softirq_MAX softirq_MIN system_AVERAGE  system_MAX  system_MIN  user_AVERAGE    user_MAX    user_MIN    ServerName  Start Time  End Time
16.3233089  16.40686623 16.19631629 0.035061225 0.050890455 0.02644959  0   0   0   0   0   0   0.003819214 0.009045636 0.001082091 0.108321254 0.133326619 0.094285539 0.126921523 0.229612047 0.060476719 devetl1.devad.myworldpanel.com  1597044600  1599633000

16.35289038 16.4473816  16.1616047  0.063374356 0.098422523 0.050224161 0   0   0   1.22E-05    7.27E-05    0   0.000824397 0.002787119 3.11E-05    0.07319389  0.120766931 0.040373169 0.106745959 0.232386044 0.052443433 devas1.devad.myworldpanel.com   1597044600  1599633000
```

Please need some idea to do this.

Comment: What you intend to do will not make a valid CSV. A csv does not have sheets, nor can you have different header lines. Try looking for examles how to import each separate csv file you have into different Excel sheets.

Comment: Echoing what @Theo said - you need to decide whether you want to merge the two formats into a single CSV (with the superset of headers from both formats), or whether you want to keep it in separate formats (ie. one file containing all `_check_cpu.csv` values, another one with the `_interface_eth0.csv` values, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Both comments are correct. You'll need to choose one of the following options:

1. Take all the headers from the two types of log files and make a single array with all the headers

```
Check CPU Array    Interface Array    Combined Array
- rx_Average       - idle_Average     - rx_Average
- rx_Max           - idle_Max         - rx_Max
- rx_Min           - idle_Min         - rx_Min
...                ...                - idle_Average
...                ...                - idle_Max
...                ...                - idle_Min
```

2. Output two separate CSV files, one for each type of log
3. Output one Excel file with two separate sheets, one for each type of log